# Java and SQL error: Unknown column 'newID' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, java, where

I have a table called colleagues and it has 6 columns: userid, firstname, lastname, title, squad, and email. The code I have typed for updating the first name is

```java
String ID = textID.getText();
String first = textFirstName.getText();
String last = textLastName.getText();
String title = textTitle.getText();
String squad = textSquad.getText();
String email = textEmail.getText();

int newID = Integer.parseInt(ID);
int newSquad = Integer.parseInt(squad);

try {
    if(first != null) {
        String sql = "Update colleagues " + "set firstname = first " + "where userid = newID";
        myStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    }
    DoConnect();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(NewJFrame.this, "Updated");
} catch (SQLException err) {
    System.out.println(err.getMessage());
}
```

The DoConnect(); after the if statement is just to update a jtable when I run the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely want to change this:

```java
String sql = "Update colleagues " + "set firstname = first " + "where userid = newID";
```

You're writing `first` and `newID` as if they were the names of columns... when you want to actually add the actual values of your variables (with adequate *escaping*)

Check [SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet: MySQL Escaping](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#MySQL_Escaping)

---

You're probably be better of with a [prepared statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) (you'll save yourself of the trouble of escaping, plus you'll have some extra documentation about the types of the parameters, plus you'll avoid risks of SQL injection):

```java
if (first != null) {
    String sql = "UPDATE colleagues SET firstname = ? WHERE userid = ?";
    // Assuming there is a global variable for the connection, named con
    PreparedStatement upd = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    upd.setString(1, first); // replace first ? with value for first name
    upd.setInt(2, newID);    // replace second ? with value for userid
    upd.executeUpdate();
}
```